# ViewFlipper having 'huge' delay

Tags: android, animation

I have a ViewFlipper which runs a view animation when showPrevious is called. The animation works out fine. But the problem is it starts with a delay of over 1 seconds. Now this doesn't seem like much but it seriously delays usage of the app.

My animations look like this;

```
Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
inFromLeft.setDuration(350);
inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());   

Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
outtoRight.setDuration(350);
outtoRight.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

I set the animations using `setInAnimation` and `setOutAnimation`;

```
setInAnimation(inFromLeft);
setOutAnimation(outtoRight);
```

And then I just launch the animation using `showPrevious`

Is there any reason why the animations starts with a delay of over 1 seconds, the startTime for the animations is -1 and the startOffset is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions.  First, if possible, change over to using ViewPager.  Second, if the first is not possible, then use XML-based animations.  Pushing stuff out of code and into resources is usually a win.

Comment: The solution was switching to the ViewPager, the animation is not exactly the one I wanted, but the delay is gone. Changing the animations to XML didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the delay is happening in the animation? Have you tried adding some logging including the startAnimation method of an AnimationListener?

If you're sure the delay is coming after you start the animation, you might try using [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html) between before you start the animation and after it's done (using an AnimationListener again). This will tell you what Android's doing in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue as @MrThys but only seeing that on Gingerbread devices. No such issues on JellyBean devices.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You are right. But I could not up-vote/comment on the actual post and am facing the same issue. Have tried XML-based animations and they have not helped.

Comment: That does not justify posting it as an answer. Wait until you have enough reputation or ask a different question yourself.